How to avoid loop in Pandas iterating unique values?
I have a table with users and times of their actions:



user_ id
time
user_action




user_1
1
action_1


user_2
2
action_2


user_1
3
action_3


user_2
4
action_4



My algorithm includes looping over unique values and taking some actions using the shift function.

users = df.user_id.unique()

df_2 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ...) # empty DataFrame

for user in users:
    df_new = df[df.user_id == user]
    df_new['...'] = df['user_action'].shift(1)....
    \ some actions using shift \

    df_2 = pd.concat([df_2, df_new])

Also, cumsums are used, so it would be impossible to implement algorithm without dividing into "df_new" pieces.
This method is too long seemingly because of using Python's "for". How can I do it using the build-in Pandas functions?

what does your expected output look like?

Seems like you should be able to do something using .groupby('user_id')

for starters, never do this in a loop: df_2 = pd.concat([df_2, df_new]). The for isn't the biggest issue. That is the main problem. As well as doing df_new = df[df.user_id == user] in the loop. As others have noted, you want to use .groupby("user_id")

Without seeing the full code, it's hard to tell exactly what you're trying to achieve.
But have you looked at DataFrame.groupby()? This returns a DataFrameGroupBy object which also offers shift() and cumsum() methods.
Thus, you may be able to rewrite your code using groupby():
df.groupby(by="user_id").shift(1).cumsum()

Another option could be DataFrameGroupby.apply(), transform() or aggregate() depending on your expected output format, applying your original logic to each group:
def your_actions(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
  ...  # whatever you did for each user

df.groupby(by="user_id").apply(your_actions)

You may get more precise answers if you provide a more complete code sample or a description what you are trying to compute using shift and cumsum, but I hope this already helps by hinting into a possible direction.

Glad to hear that and good luck with your programming :)
